# Is HelveticaNeue a good web/e-mail typeface if it can successfully embedded?

Tags: typography, web-fonts, typefaces, e-mail

I need to send some professional/commercial e-mails, my design currently look like this:

[image: screenshot of a web browser version]

Helvetica is very widely used in printing, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica):

> Miedinger and Hoffmann set out to create a neutral typeface that had **great clarity**, no intrinsic meaning in its form, and could be used on a wide variety of signage.

But [many people](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13823) state that its use [should be limited to printing](http://www.64notes.com/design/stop-helvetica-arial/) as it makes a poor web font with the two main reason being:

- The font looks ugly *(but they don't talk about Helvetica Neue and its 51 versions)*
- Most users don't have the font, and Windows systematically redirect its call to Arial via registry key *(but they don't talk about embedding legally a subset)*. In the case of e-mails they also tell support to`@font-face` is very poor *(which is true, but they don't talk about the combination of several other fall-back methods which "solve" this issue)*.

The second reason is the most important, because the suggested replacements I saw : widely available on users computers, which means "using non-professional typefaces" but which are safe value *(still without considering embedding)*.

**So, does HelveticaNeue is a good typeface strictly in terms of legibility?**
Or a different typeface would be better... *even a serif one?*

Comment: Well, the e-mail program of the receiver of the e-mail can be figured to show the e-mail with fonts the receiver wants to see.  That's the reason I spend more time for the content of the e-mail and less for the layout.

Comment: @Kurt : Not necessarily, just read [my comment](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/is-helveticaneue-a-good-web-e-mail-typeface#comment58173_41530). Additionally I created a fall-back for viewing the e-mail in a plain dedicated web-browser page. So I'm near sure this the right font which will displayed. But yes, I focused myself on the content during a long time before asking this question.

Comment: Assume that people will **not** "click here to view in a browser". They don't — if they can't get what they want when opening the email, they'll delete it and move on with their lives.

Comment: @StanRogers : Yes, but that's why I design the mail so it should still display an acceptable design despite restrictions *(by using only static images, don't use div but tables... (I recognize this won't be exactly the result of the screenshot))*. And I'm sure the right font will be displayed in near all the case.

Comment: "professional emails", IMHO, should be plain text.

Comment: Also, if I'm on my phone, I appreciate email not sucking down more of my data plan than necessary.

Comment: Embedding Helvetica Neue for web usage is fine--especially for headings.

Comment: Is there *that much* of a difference with Helvetica Neue that you really absolutely honest-to-smurf have to have *that font* rather than just "Helvetica/Arial"? We're not even talking a huge distinction like Trade Gothic, Avant Garde, or Futura. You're talking about two different kinds of *Helvetica*. Why are you opening yourself up to so many kinds of technical difficulties for so little difference?

Comment: @DA01 : Yes embedding it legally will work too. but due to the number critics which target it's non re-worked "ancestor" *(Helvetica in the 60's : saying it's an ugly choice in case of web (still the best choice for printing), even compared to non professional font)*. I've some doubt about that choice.

Comment: Helvetica is arguably the most succesful typeface ever. It's perhaps the most used corporate typeface around. I don't know that I'd take critiques of it as being 'unprofessional' too seriously.

Comment: Hummm... You would heart professional typographers and designer @LaurenIpsum :-). Arial was written as lower cost alternative to Helvetica, so it is considered a [very poor choice](http://www.64notes.com/images/design/typography-wierd-helvetica-and-lucida-grande-and-arial.jpg) both for clarity and beauty. Helvetica was designed in the 60's : a time were numerical displays only existed at Palo Alto. So it work only for printed documents and it require custom kerning. HelveticaNeue is a wide family designed to partial address some Helvetica issues, but professionals don't really talk about it.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum : Also I don't want to compare HelveticaNeue to Helvetica and Arial. I'm thinking at comparing to a completely different typeface if is not the best choice.

Comment: @DA01 : Yes, but every formal document can be printed. The only case is for web pages/e-mails which is make a recent one comparing to the age of Helvetica. Some peoples with trained eyes says they refuse to read if they see the first words are written in Arial.As I'm planning to send my e-mails to Printing companies *(yes, you won't send design a e-mail to tell your colleague a planning change)*.I recognize going to get my e-mails not be read because of a font choice is a little unlikely.I don't want to show complete ignorance in the targeted field.So I'm considered the font choice seriously.

Comment: Unless your target audience is 'trained eyed Arial haters' I wouldn't put a lot of weight into that argument. It is fair to say that both Arial and Helvetica were not designed specifically for screen usage. Though with higher-density screens, it's less of an issue today. If the goal is readability, stick with the basics designed for the screen. Remember the typeface people likely prefer for email is the typeface that they see by default in their email client. There's not a strong argument IMHO to over-ride that.

Comment: @DA01 : And How you can configure the default tyepface you see for web clients in, let's say Outlook365 or gmail?

Comment: It's buried in preferences somewhere in Outlook. Not sure about Gmail. Point is few people bother to do so, so they get used to whatever the default text is in their email client. I would argue that's the best option to go with--at least for body text.

Comment: I think that professional Emails should always contain a plain text and a HTML version. You can embed Helvica in the Email and people will see it if they allow HTML, but it will be impossible for you to use it when the other user wants a plain text mail.

Answer (score 3):

When designing for emails, I go for the lowest common denominator.

If a particular font is important, limit it to *a few words* and make it a graphic. Otherwise, just assume "serif/sans serif" and don't try to design with fonts.

There is no way to control or predict what the user will have installed, what email client is being used, or what version of what email client is being used. That's not even counting desktop vs. phone vs. tablet.

You can make a case for "Helvetica/Arial" vs. "Times," but not for "Helevetica Neue." And you can do all sorts of things with embedded fonts on the web. But in emails? Design as simply as possible with as much flexibility as possible, so you don't risk breakage.

Comment: e-mails have more support than `@font-face`. You can also use `@import`and even fall-back to a classical `<link rel=...>`. So I'm getting a large % support, even for webmail clients `(checked with commons clients of both type)`. Sorry, if t was unclear, but I'm planning, to embedded subsets of HelveticaNeue :  that was because of that I was talking about font-embedding. So if I use HelveticaNeue *(Roman 55 or Light)*, I'm sure it that that font which will be displayed in near all cases.

Comment: @user2284570 Won't that bloat the emails file size substantially? Have you looked at the file size of an email with an embedded font? I'm not sure if it matters with emails but I figure it's a good idea in general to keep file sizes as low as possible.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter : I don't write my e-mails in an Asian writing system :). The subset I use add 5 to 18 Ko. It depends on the number of different characters I use in the e-mail. This result in a ~98Ko e-mail with attachments included.

Comment: @user2284570 yes but you just sent that 100k to a thousand persons and now it is 100 megs

Comment: @joojaa : Yes, but this is for formal e-mails : I send a different text for each recipient : so I write them manually. It make sending 1k unlikely. The best way to decrease the size of my e-mails would be to remove the forms which are send as an attachment, but it can't be. Also, I was using regular printed postal mails some years ago to do this *(helvetica was the best font here for sure)*.

Comment: @user2284570 You really can't replicate a printed piece perfectly on the web, and definitely not in an email. You need to get as close as reasonable, and I think "Helvetica/Arial" is the best you can hope for.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum : Yes, that's why I'm changing to complete different design *(leaving black and white A4 PDF)* to change to something which is better on screened than printed *(the final phase of electronic switch)*. I can already circumvent gmail and outlook365 sanitizer with embedding font (tested). I also tested for thunderbird/outlook. So I'm not sure about my design, but I'm sure the right font choice will be applied *(except if the user force a font he think is the best one; but it is not a problem in that case)*.